# Почему при сравнение input выводит не правильное значение

Tags: javascript, input, javascript-events

Почему правильно сравнение работает только тогда, когда input2 больше. Мне надо сделать так чтобы мы водили значение в input они сравнивались и выводилось большое

```js
let inputI31 = document.querySelector('.i-31');
let inputI32 = document.querySelector('.i-32');
let btnB3 = document.querySelector('.b-3');
let out3 = document.querySelector('.out-3')

btnB3.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (inputI31.value > inputI32.value) {
    out3.innerHTML = inputI31.value;
  } else {
    out3.innerHTML = inputI32.value;
  }
})
```

```html
<section>
  <h4>Task 3.</h4>
  <p>Даны 2 input - .i-31 и .i-32, оба - input[type=number]. При нажатии кнопки .b-3 срабатывает функция f3. Функция должна сравнить числа из input, вывести в .out-3 большее число</p>
  <p>Проведите самостоятельный тест работы, введите пары чисел 4 и 9, 9 и 22, 5 и 111.</p>
  <div><input type="number" class="i-31" value="33"></div>
  <div><input type="number" class="i-32" value="9"></div>
  <button class="button-primary b-3">Task-3</button>
  <div class="out-3"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы сравниваете строки "33" и "9" вместо чисел. Для корректного сравнения надо сначала преобразовать строки в число, например функцией `parseInt()`

```js
let inputI31 = document.querySelector('.i-31');
let inputI32 = document.querySelector('.i-32');
let btnB3 = document.querySelector('.b-3');
let out3 = document.querySelector('.out-3')

btnB3.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let i31 = parseInt(inputI31.value);
  let i32 = parseInt(inputI32.value);
  if (i31 > i32) {
    out3.innerHTML = inputI31.value;
  } else {
    out3.innerHTML = inputI32.value;
  }
})
```

```html
<section>
  <h4>Task 3.</h4>
  <p>Даны 2 input - .i-31 и .i-32, оба - input[type=number]. При нажатии кнопки .b-3 срабатывает функция f3. Функция должна сравнить числа из input, вывести в .out-3 большее число</p>
  <p>Проведите самостоятельный тест работы, введите пары чисел 4 и 9, 9 и 22, 5 и 111.</p>
  <div><input type="number" class="i-31" value="33"></div>
  <div><input type="number" class="i-32" value="9"></div>
  <button class="button-primary b-3">Task-3</button>
  <div class="out-3"></div>
</section>
```